# Loss of nautilus menu functionality in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: unity, nautilus, xfce, dropbox

As you'll see from the following image, my copy of nautilus is a little broken.

[image: broken-nautilus]

I've lost access to all menus other than "file", there are black spots on the top corners of the window, and the file/folder icons are much larger than they were previously.

For reference, here as an image of how nautilus used to look (and how I'd like it to look!)

[image: unbroken-nautilus]

I think this has happened because I recently installed budgie as an alternate desktop. Other possible causes: I recently installed dropbox, and I also recently installed another alternate desktop (xfce4).

Attempted fixes so far (followed by system restart):

1. Purge Dropbox, Bugie, Xfce and Thunar:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge dropbox budgie-desktop xfce4 thunar
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
2. Run Unity and Nautilus in separate sessions:

   ```
   setsid unity
   setsid nautilus
   ```
3. Preferred applications > Utilities > File Manager > Nautilus
4. Reinstall Nautilus:

   ```
   sudo apt-get --reinstall install nautilus
   ```

So far, nothing has worked.

Answer (score 2):

The budgie-remix PPA includes a version of nautilus that does not have the unity patchwork to display menus.

budgie-desktop does not work very well with the older version of Nautilus in the main repository for 16.04.  This issue only affects 16.04 users - 16.10 and later versions use the main repository version of Nautilus.

Given that you have purged budgie-desktop I presume you have finished experimenting.  You will need to purge the PPA as well so that nautilus is downgraded from the GTK+3.18 version in the PPA to the older GTK+3.14 version that is in the main repo.

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:budgie-remix/ppa
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've since rolled back to my previous Ubuntu backup, so I can't confirm either way if this resolves the issue, but I'll definitely purge the ppa if it's on my system.
This is also helpful information which has given me a better understanding of the dependencies involved with different GUIs.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then

```
setsid unity
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I did this and restarted the system, but it didn't work.